# Have DEM, need polygon outlining region above a certain elevation

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis, dem

I have a DEM in HGT format. I need to isolate all areas above a certain elevation and view them as polygons. Something like this (let's say the pink polygon is everything above 1000m):

[image: DEM to polygon example]

Seems like this would be a common GIS task, but all I found is the GRASS `r.lake` function. What I need is the *opposite* of a lake. :) QGIS/Python/GRASS solutions are preferred.

Comment: Reclassify into 2 classes, convert to polygons should work

Comment: @jbalk: how would I do that? A full answer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

[image]

[image]
[image]

**Convert line to polygon tool**

[image]

To isolate area you can Clip DEM with polygon.
I hope that is it.

Comment: Perfect! I used the GRASS `r.contour.step` command for the contour lines, then Vector > Geometry tools > Lines to polygons. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `r.recode` to extract the areas above a certain altitude, and then `r.to.vect` to convert the resulting raster layer to a vector layer. The steps:

#### Import the data

You can import the data in a grass gis database using r.in.gdal or using the 'import raster data' menu (for more details see the grass wiki page [Import of original SRTM tiles in HGT format](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/HOWTO_import_SRTM_elevation_data#Import_of_original_SRTM_tiles_in_HGT_format).

[image: Import raster data]

#### Extract the area of interest

Next, you have various options to 'extract' the areas above a certain altitude, including the [r.mapcalc](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/r.mapcalc.html), [r.reclass](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/r.reclass.html) and [r.recode](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/r.recode.html). In the example below, the *r.recode* function is used to reclassify all cells of the elevation map with a altitude > 120 to 1. The rest will be assigned a NULL (nodata) value.

[image: Recode a raster layer]

Note that the field marked with the blue asterisk will be automatically filled in (it is the path to a temporary file) when you enter the recode rule in the field below.

#### Convert from raster to vector

You can now convert the resulting raster layer to vector layer with the [r.to.vect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfQZI.png) function.

[image: Convert the raster layer 'highareas' to the vector polygon layer 'highareas']

#### Or all in once

You can use the steps above on the command line in one go:

```
r.recode input=elevation output=highareas rules=- << EOF
120:*:1
EOF
r.to.vect -s input=elevation@PERMANENT output=highareas type=area
```

#### And the result

This gives you a vector map of all areas with an altitude > 120.

[image: Elevation map from the North Carolina sample dataset, overlaid with a vector layer (transparent blue area) with the areas with an altitude > 120]

Answer (score 1):

Just use QGIS:

1. From the raster bar open the **raster_calculator** and perform your query, e.g.:

   `"myDTM@1" > 1000`

   Result must be saved in a new raster, e.g.,"myDTM1000"
2. From raster bar -> conversion open the **polygonize** tool and convert this raster into a polygon.

QGIS **polygonize** tool is based on a gdal function. You can even use directly gdal if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Using GRASS raster calculator I would isolate the desired elevation as a binary raster and then convert is as a polygon.

With two commands in GRASS console:

```
r.mapcalc expression="elevation_1km = if(elevation >=10000 , 1, null())"
```

and then make it a polygon

```
r.to.vect -v input=elevation_1km output=elevation_poly type=area
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a quick way to do this in R using the raster and sf (simple features) packages:

```
dem <- raster("location of dem")
contours <- rasterToContour(dem)
contours <- st_as_sf(contours )
contour.poly <- st_polygonize(contours)
contour.poly <- st_collection_extract(contour.poly )
st_cast(contour.poly, "MULTIPOLYGON")
```

once you have the contour.poly you can use any of the sf geometry operations. Also, you may want to reduce the resolution of the DEM else it will take ages.