# How to draw a polygon of all points in a certain height range

Tags: qgis, polygon

At the moment I have a raster file of elevations, and I am interested in creating a polygon that consists of all points whose heights are between x and y. So its boundaries will be the union of the x and y contours. Is this possible to do?

n.b. There is a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297943/have-dem-need-polygon-outlining-region-above-a-certain-elevation) asked before, but I am extremely new to QGIS so the answers are not useful to me at all since they assume a lot higher familiarity with QGIS than I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create contours at all.
Use the raster calculator to create a binary mask from your elevation layer. The formula is something like

```
"your_layer@1" > x AND "your_layer@1" <= y
```

This will create a new layer that is white for the elevations of interest and black everywhere else.

Now apply polygonize (raster to vector) from the Processing toolbox to create a polygon (vector) layer. The processing algorithm will create an attribute DN by default (or something else if you change it). The polygons you want have DN = 1, the others have DN = 0. Open the attribute table and select the features with DN = 0 and delete them. What's left is what you were trying to create.

To create polygons for multiple levels (per OP comment), use this formula in the raster calculator:

```
("your_layer@1" > x1 AND "your_layer@1" <= y1) * 1 +
("your_layer@1" > x2 AND "your_layer@1" <= y2) * 2 +
("your_layer@1" > x3 AND "your_layer@1" <= y3) * 3
```

Each elevation band will have a different value for the DN attribute which you can use to identify the polygons for each elevation range. For more levels, just extend the pattern of the formula.

(Note: I initially created a temporary layer for the binary mask layer, but the processing algorithm requires the layer be a file. If you get an error trying to run polygonize this might be the reason. Just export your binary mask to disk as a geotiff file and try again.)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if it's possible to mass produce new layers, between heights x_1 and y_1, x_2 and y_2, ... , x_n and y_n?

Comment: Also I have a problem polygonising the raster layers created, I think because they are saved in a Temp file? I get the error message: 
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/[file location].gpkg
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, your problem is that it's a temp layer. Save the temp layer to a geotiff, then try polygonize.

Comment: Is there any way to batch save many raster layers without using python?